# Bootstrap JQuery posting wrong data elements to PHP mail

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am writing a wedding website with a basic form to get the guest email address, guest name(s), guest dinner option, the number of children they are bringing, and a requested song they would like played. I then want to take these values and send them via PHP mail function to an email address. Here is what I have so far:

Here is the snippet of my javascript. The variables emailAddr, g1_name, and g1_dinner all have the correct values in them when I log it to the console.

```
var data = {
            email : emailAddr,
            g1Name : g1_name,
            g1Dinner : g1_dinner
            };

$.post("email.php", data, function(){
            alert("Email Success");
        });
```

Here is the PHP:

```
     <?php
            $to = "test@email.com";
            $from = $_POST['email'];
            $guestName_1 = $_POST['g1Name'];
            $guestDinner_1 = $_POST['g1Dinner'];
            $message = "Email: "+$from +"\n\nGuest 1: "+$guestName_1+" - "+$guestDinner_1;
            $message = wordwrap($message, 70);

            mail($to,"Wedding RSVP",$message);
    ?>
```

Here is what is actually getting POST'd:
[image]

And here is the email I get from my web host:

[image]

So my main question is why is what is getting POST to my PHP file different than I am specifying?

And a follow up, why am I getting emailed a 0 and not the string I set?

And is this the right way to do something like this?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 101: String concatenation uses `.`, you're using `+`, which is mathematical addition.

```
'string' + 'string' => generally "0" or wonky integer as result
'string' . 'string' => 'stringstring'
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that I kept trying to figure out why it was POSTing incorrectly, this was exactly the answer!